# Name Error when passing a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program and keep on getting trouble with the error:

```
   File "C:/Users//Documents///", line 47, in                      <module>
print(operations(sorted_list_desc))
NameError: name 'sorted_list_desc' is not defined
```

Even though you can not see the file I am working with, I have provided my code. I am supposed to loop the years and randomly choose an operator for each of the years. However, I keep on getting the error above. Any ideas why I keep on getting it?

```
import csv

#List to store different operators
list_operators = ["+","-","*","/"]


#Function to read file of list
def read_file():

#List to store data
    sorted_list_desc = []

 year = csv_file.readline()
    population = csv_file.readline()


    return sorted_list_desc

     print(read_file())

def operations(sorted_list_desc):
    for i in range(len(sorted_list_desc)):
        operator = random.choice(list_operator)
    return operator
print(operations(sorted_list_desc))
##
```

Comment: Can you include your full code? Where do you call `print(operations(sorted_list_desc))`?

Comment: have done, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted_list_desc` is generated by `read_file()`. Change your last line to:

```
print(operations(read_file()))
```

The line:

```
print(read_file())
```

does not magically created a global object withe name `sorted_list_desc`.
You need to hand it over explicitly to `operations()`.

Alternatively, you could write:

```
sorted_list_desc = read_file()
print(operations(sorted_list_desc))
```

Comment: Thank You!! helped

Answer (score 1):

You have only assigned `sorted_list_desc` *inside* your function `read_file()`. Thus, your error is telling you that `sorted_list_desc` is not assigned to anything outside your function's scope. See [Python scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules), and notice that you don't even need to pass `sorted_list_desc` as a parameter because it is assigned inside your function anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sorted_list_desc` is defined within the scope of your `read_file()` function and thus you can't reference it outside of that function. You can call `print(operations(sorted_list_desc))` within 'read_file()', or you can define `sorted_list_desc = []` at a global scope.